# How can you get a DEVICE_OBJECT from the name of the device?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, low-level, windows-kernel

How can you get a DEVICE_OBJECT from the name of the device using the wdk?

Comment: you can create file on this device object ( NtOpenFile, NtCreateFile, IoCreateFile) or even use ObOpenObjectByName (with IoFileObjectType). IoGetDeviceObjectPointer call ZwOpenFile + IoGetRelatedDeviceObject) in all case you can got pointer not exactly to this device object, but device attached to it or low level device in stack